# Cannot load ggplot2 in juypter notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to install the `library(caret)` but keep getting this error in juypter notebook.
I also tried `install.packages("ggplot2)` and then `library(ggplot2)` but nothing works.
Also `install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)` but the same error

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(kknn)
library(AUC)
library(MASS)


"package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3"Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace 'rlang' 0.3.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
Error: package 'ggplot2' could not be loaded
Traceback:

1. library(caret)
2. .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
3. stop(gettextf("package %s could not be loaded", sQuote(pkg)), 
 .     call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP.  I've seen this type of error before when loading/installing a package.  Pay close attention to the text of the error - in particular, this part should jump out at you:

```
namespace 'rlang' 0.3.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
```

From that line, it seems that your version of `rlang` will need to be updated first.  Try the following:

```
install.packages('rlang')

# wait for install

install.packages('ggplot2')
```